# How to connect azure function with google storage

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-authentication

i try to connect my azure function to google cloud storage and I have some issues with the authentication.
I am able to connece everythin from my JupyterNotebook but in my azure function I am not able to provide the credentials as path. In my azure function I am not able to provide a path but have the credentials in a variable. It returns the error `Exception: OSError: [Errno 63] File name too long`. I think the error occures because it treads the credentials as path.
I could not find a way to connect to google storage toll now.

Here is a super short version of what I did to get the client:

```
from google.cloud import storage

google_credentials = get_credentials()
client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(google_credentials)
```

Any suggestions how I can connect with a service account to google within an azure function?

Best :-)

Comment: What is the content of `google_credentials`? What is its type?

Comment: Hello @guillaumeblaquiere and thanks for your answer.
The type is ```<class 'google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials'>```

SInce this morning I worked on the problem and have an other idea where I get a different error message:

```
path_to_key = '<<<PATH TO JSON FILE>>>'

service_account_info = json.load(open(path_to_key))
google_credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
    service_account_info
)
client = storage.Client(credentials=google_credentials)
```
here the error message is
```DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine....```

Comment: ```...credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```
the error message does not help an all because I think that I provide the credentials explicitly

Comment: You can't store file locally and temporarily on Azure Functions, like the `/tmp` directory? Anyway, if you have a path like in your previous comment, simply do this `client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(<CREDENTIAL_PATH>)`

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I totally agree with your answer but I do not have a path. This was only for local testing in my Jupyter notebook.
I am looking for a solution where I can read the JSON from my key vault and login into google storage

Comment: The focus of the question changed a los so I decided to start a new conversation:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63561032/how-to-log-in-google-storage-from-a-python-function

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I saw that the code that I am using needs a path as argument. I delivered the credentials.