# How to log into Google Cloud Storage from a python function?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-authentication, google-auth-library

I am new to google cloud storage and I try to set up a function that downloads a blob once a day.
At the moment I am working in my Jupyter Notebook but finally, the code will run in an Azure Function. I am struggling with setting up the client that connects me to the bucket. I have a service account credential JSON which enables me to connect to google.

Locally I have found a solution:

```
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('<PATH_TO_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON>')
```

The problem is that I do not have a path where I store my JSON in the cloud but I store it in the key vault.
I came up with the following solution:

```
from google.cloud import storage
import json
from google.oauth2 import service_account

string_key = get_key_from_key_vault()
service_account_info = json.loads(string_key)
google_credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
    service_account_info
)
scoped_credentials = google_credentials.with_scopes(
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only'])
print(type(scoped_credentials))
client = storage.Client(credentials = scoped_credentials)
```

I am not totally sure if I need the `scoped_credentials = ...`part but I only have read permissions on the bucket. (if I skip the part the error stays the same)

When I go for this solution I get the following error:

```
DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set 
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For
 more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```

I do not have a clue what I am doing wrong because I think that I already set the credentials explicitly.

Best
P

Comment: It's the correct way to do,I don't know why it doesn't work. I also don't know what is this `path_to_key`. Of you have a path, you can directly use it in the storage client.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, thanks for your answer. Thanks for the comment. There was a copy paste error in the code. I edited it seconds ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some more tests i found out that I missed to add `project = None`.
If you add it an use the following command to create the client it works:

```
client = storage.Client(project = None, credentials = scoped_credentials)
```

Thanks for your help and food for thought :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can set the environment variable [`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#setting_the_environment_variable) with the path of the json file and authenticate your function by starting the storage client without parameters.

`client = storage.Client()`

**by default the storage client uses the file path on the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`*

It is the easiest way to use JSON credentials and it is compatible with most of Google Cloud python libraries.

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer,
I totally understand your answer but I am looking for a solution where I do not have to store my JSON file in the storage. I want to read it from a key vault and this is where my problem starts :-(
Best, P

Answer (score 0):

*(I use the answer part because code formatting in comment is awful)*

Can  you try this and tell me if you see the 2 access token printed?

```
from google.cloud import storage
import json
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport import requests as grequests

string_key = get_key_from_key_vault()
service_account_info = json.loads(string_key)

google_credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
    service_account_info
)
google_credentials.refresh(grequests.Request())
print(google_credentials.token)


scoped_credentials = google_credentials.with_scopes(
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only'])
scoped_credentials.refresh(grequests.Request())
print(scoped_credentials.token)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tested your code and I can only see the second token (with scope). The first rises an error:
```RefreshError: ('invalid_scope: Invalid OAuth scope or ID token audience provided.', '{"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"Invalid OAuth scope or ID token audience provided."}')```